# converting string to integer in nested list - python

Tags: python

I am a fresher to python.

I am trying to get
`[[7, 1], [8], [4, 0, 5]]` this as result but I am keep getting `[['7, 1'], ['8'], ['4, 0, 5']]`.

```
def nested_list(f):
    opener = open(f,"r")
    lst =[lin.strip().split(" , ") for lin in opener]
    return lst
```

How can I correct my code?

Comment: Even though you see numbers in the file, python doesn't know it's dealing with number types, it assumes you have a string, since that's what you are doing by separating the array by its commas and putting it into an array. So you need to cast each of those strings or chars to an integer. https://pythonspot.com/datatype-casting/

Comment: You can also just cast it when you want to access each element int(lin[0][0]).

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend using a context manager to handle file objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it into an `int` from `string`. One way to do it is using `map`

```
def nested_list(f):
    opener = open(f,"r")
    lst = [map(int, lin.strip().split(" , ")) for lin in opener]
    return lst
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question accurately represents the file, it looks like the following, with **one space** after the comma:

```
7, 1
8
4, 0, 5
```

Use this:

```
def nested_list(f):
    with open(f) as opener:  # so the file is closed automatically.
        return [[int(x) for x in lin.strip().split(', ')] for lin in opener]
```

Answer (score 0):

In place of **int** you can use **eval** function in both above answer.Int function give error when your string contain special char while eval work smoothly